# set md-paginator values dynamically

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material2

I am trying to use `pagination` of `angular-material2` . The problem I am facing is to set the values of `md-paginator` dynamically through a service.

I have managed to create the pagination using static values but I dont know how to set them dynamically.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/D83TqrvlZmYHCeOWjGoT?p=preview)

**TS**

```
import {Component,ChangeDetectorRef, Input,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';
import {MdPaginator,PageEvent} from '@angular/material';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-http-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-http-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-http-example.html',
})
export class TableHttpExample {
  displayedColumns = ['dbquery', 'title'];
  exampleDatabase: ExampleHttpDatabase | null;
  dataSource: ExampleDataSource | null;
   pageEvent: PageEvent;

  @ViewChild(MdPaginator) paginator: MdPaginator;

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }
  ngOnInit(){
     this.loadData();
  }
  loadData(){
    this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleHttpDatabase(this.http);
    this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase,this.paginator);
  }
   onPaginateChange(event){

     const startIndex = event.pageIndex * event.pageSize;

      this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase,this.paginator);

  }
}

/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
export class ExampleHttpDatabase {
  private issuesUrl = 'https://emgrweb.ecwcloud.com/eManagerWeb/rest/InterfaceQAClientController/getInterfaceClientScripts';  // URL to web API

  getRepoIssues(startIndex,pageSize): Observable<any> {
   var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    var requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: this.issuesUrl,
            headers: headers
            body : "start=" +startIndex +"&limit="+ pageSize
          })

      return this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions)).map(this.extractData);
  }

  extractData(result: Response): any{
    return result.json().data.map(data => {
      return data

    });
  }
  onPaginateChange(event){
    //alert(JSON.stringify(event));
     const startIndex = event.pageIndex * event.pageSize;
//     this.drugmap.getDrugDataForClient(startIndex, event.pageSize); 
     this.dataSource = new BindDataTableSource(this.drugmap,event);

  }
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
}

export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private _exampleDatabase: ExampleHttpDatabase,private _paginator : MdPaginator) {
    super();
  }

  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<any[]> {
    console.log( this._paginator);
     const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
    return this._exampleDatabase.getRepoIssues(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
  }

  disconnect() {}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="dbquery">
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> dbquery </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.title}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="title">
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Title </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.title}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>



    <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
    <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>

  </md-table>
       <md-paginator #paginator
              [length]="100"
              [pageIndex]="0"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
               (page)="pageEvent = $event; onPaginateChange($event)"
               >
    </md-paginator>
</div>
```

Tried passing the `paginator` object to `ExampleHttpDatabase` but when I `console` it out, it says undefined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change the values dynamically, use variables as inputs to the `<md-paginator>`. When those variables change, the paginator will pick them up and render them to the view.

```
<md-paginator #paginator
             [length]="myExampleLength"
             [pageIndex]="myExamplePageIndex"
             [pageSize]="myExamplePageSize"
             [pageSizeOptions]="myExamplePageSizeOptions"
             (page)="pageEvent = $event; onPaginateChange($event)">
</md-paginator>
```

Comment: I tried something and have updated the plunker, but unfortunately the value which is set is `undefined`. Could you please have a look and help?

Comment: Couple issues, sometimes you call it `pagerLength` and something you call it `pageLength`. Biggest issue is that you are not calling `extractData` in the right `this` context. Check out this plunker for a fixed example: https://plnkr.co/edit/BBdEKJ4WnJVBetZR4AkY?p=preview

Comment: I looked at the plunker Andrew added. Question:  The plnkr method onPaginateChange(event) has the following line:

this.dataSource = new BindDataTableSource(this.drugmap,event);

BindDataTableSource doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. What is it? Could you please fix the plnkr if possible? Thanks!